# how to add special character in a varchar column in between char and number

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to add "_" in a column which is VARCHAR.

The column value is like ABSC124DBV
I want to add "_" between char and number for it to look like ABSC_124_DBV.

Is there a sql function to achieve this.

Comment: oracle data base

Comment: Please show your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 6):

On Oracle we can try doing a regex replacement here:

```
SELECT
    val,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        REGEXP_REPLACE(val, '([A-Z])([0-9])', '\1_\2'),
        '([0-9])([A-Z])',
        '\1_\2'
    ) AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

The regex logic used above to match either of the following:

- `([A-Z])([0-9])`
- `([0-9])([A-Z])`

For each such match, we replace with the same letter/number (or vice versa) with an underscore inserted in between them.

Comment: can you please explain what '\1_\2' is doing. I am new to sql. Please don't mind.

Comment: The `\1` and `\2` refer to the first and second _capture_ groups.  In this case, the first and second capture groups would be a letter A-Z or number 0-9 (or vice versa).

Comment: @ARH: \1 and \2 have nothing to do with SQL. They represent parts of a regular expression. Regular expressions can be used in some SQL dialects, in several programming languages, some text editors, etc. So, if you want to learn more about this powerful feature, look for regular expression tutorials, not SQL tutorials.